# Creeper fall damage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many blocks do creepers need to fall to ensure they die on impact?

Answer (score 4):

> Fall damage is 1 half heart for each block fallen after the third.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Fall_damage).

This applies to all mobs. Thus 20 + 3 + 1 = 24. A creeper has to fall 24 blocks to die.

A player takes half a heart of damage when falling for 4 blocks, a heart for 5, and so on.

Comment: This is not quite true. You actually need 23.5 blocks to be fatal, so one needs 24 blocks for practical mob farms. See the source you quoted. :)

Answer (score -9):

A player will take half a heart when falling 3 blocks. Same as a creeper. A player has the same amount of health points as the creeper, 20 health points. Multiply 20 by 3 to get 60. So, the creeper has to fall 60 blocks down to die.

Comment: This is quite wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: Jim, if that is true, I would dare you to literally go jump off of a cliff... i.e. try falling 50 blocks. If your hypothesis is valid, you should be fine! :L

Comment: @user1337 jumped 60 blocks down underground and died. Got half a heart when jumping 30-40 blocks down.

Comment: @jim were you wearing armor during your jump? You can't wear armor for this test. And ending with half a heart on ~30 is implying that if you fall 20 more blocks it wouldn't do more damage at all?

Comment: @Arperum no, but now I understand I'm wrong.